# Owin InvalidOperation exception at startup in Authentication or Map middleware

Tags: asp.net, iis, owin

We have a regular asp.net web app and added Owin based OpenID Connect authentication (AzureAD). On my local machine on *IIS Express* the Owin startup was not triggered at all, even though the *Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb* dll was there, we had tried also with settings like the `owin:AutomaticAppStartup` and `owin:appStartup`, nothing changed. 
Only solution that made Owin work locally was to Initialize it in Global.asax.cs WebApplication ctor by calling `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.PreApplicationStart.Initialize();`

When we deployed to Azure (Cloud Service, we have access for the hosting VM) on IIS the app is throwing the following Stack Trace during the OnStart of the webrole:

```
[InvalidOperationException]: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.PushLastObjects(IDictionary`2 environment, TaskCompletionSource`1 completionSource)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.Epilog(IDictionary`2 env)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.DefaultAppInvoked(IDictionary`2 env)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->
```

Does anyone have any clue where and what might be causing the problem? I don't have a deep understanding of the Owin internals and how the pipeline is initialized so I am not sure based on this trace whether this is at app startup or during an actual request, but since it does not contain any code of our implementation I suppose it fails at startup. Maybe on regular IIS Owin did start normally unlike in IIS Express, and that extra call in Global.asax is causing this weird exception?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure why Owin is breaking in such a cryptic way, the main cause it turned out was indeed the explicit `PreApplicationStart.Initialize()` call, as on IIS the startup run normally just by having the *SystemWeb* , and apparently the initialization of the Owin request processing module is not re-entrant at all.
We changed the code to only do the explicit initialization on Local environments, and it now works as expected both an IIS in the cloud and IIS Express locally.